# Is it true that blowing up a quasi-affine variety at a nonsingular point never introduces new singularities?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, singularity-theory, blowup

If we let $M$ be a quasi-affine variety, is it true in general that the blowup of $M$ at a non-singular point $p$ does not introduce new singularities? I came across this statement in my reading, but I'm not actually convinced that this is true. Am I missing a simple argument?

Comment: Yes, it is true: the blow-up is an isomorphism away from the point you are blowing up at.

Comment: @Marie: you're right that it's true, but I'm not sure your comment is a convincing explanation. I think the main issue is why the blow-up is nonsingular along the exceptional divisor.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh You are right.

Comment: To the OP: this is Theorem II. 8.24 in Hartshorne.

Comment: Just as an extra comment to Marie's reference, if you don't like Hartshorne's highbrow approach, you can do things more concretely. Assume wlog that $M$ is affine, say with a closed embedding $M \subset \mathbf{A}^n$. You can work out the equations of the blowup of $\mathbf{A}^n$ in a nonsingular point $p$ of $M$, then use those to find the equations of the blowup of $M$ itself, in particular to see $M$ is nonsingular along the exceptional divisor.

Comment: The local picture of such a blowup would be the blowup of affine space at a point. Such a blowup can be described as a gluing of copies of affine space along open subsets -- certainly nonsingular.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not sure I follow your argument. If $M$ is not rational, no open set in $M$ is isomorphic to an open set in affine space. (Morally, of course, you are right, but a rigorous argument along these lines would seem to need something more than the Zariski topology.)

Comment: Dear @AsalBeagDubh, it's probably best to take it as a moral argument if one is not working over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Marie: do you want to write your comment as an answer? There's something very unsatisfying about leaving such a question in the "unanswered" category.